# Wordpress 4.4 upgrade visual editor bullets select for not selected elements

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, visual-editor

Please check attachment for reference image and help me to fix it please.

[image]

Comment: I find it hard to understand which problem you are facing. To facilitate giving helpful answers you may want to consider giving more details what's not working as expected and what you have tried to fix it.

Comment: In wp-admin edited post and tried to set numbered bullets for selected text. It's adding bullets for not selected text as well. It's issue for wordpress version 4.4 it's working fine still wordpress version of 3.9.9

Comment: So, you don't want "related reports" to have bullet? Not quite understanding your question.

Comment: I want to remove "Related reports" bullets. The bullets are display only for selected text it should display to not selected text.

Comment: Select the text editor instead of the visual editor, then, copy and paste this <ul><li>Related reports</li></ul> and add the text under that.

Comment: I have lots of contents not an single post. I know this solution but I have thousands of posts, I will not change every single posts yaar. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded word press version to 3.9.9 and fixed issue.